# I'm trying to write a query in PostgreSQL to extract text between 4th and 5th , (comma)

Tags: sql, postgresql

This query works in Oracle please let me know how to extract text in **postgresql**

```
Select regexp_sustr('abc,afgg,afff,eef esfg eg,gegg,egegeg,vgb,grgg','[^,]+',1,5)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regex replacement trick here:

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(
    'abc,afgg,afff,eef esfg eg,gegg,egegeg,vgb,grgg',
    '^([^,]+,){3}|,.*$', '', 'g') AS output;  -- eef esfg eg
```

### Demo

This approach strips off the first 3 CSV terms and the 4th comma until the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

Use `split_part` instead to efficiently obtain the n-th field given a delimiter:

```
select split_part('abc,afgg,afff,eef esfg eg,gegg,egegeg,vgb,grgg', ',', 5);
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=5a3dd70a3793e3588d300bbb61dcf0b6

If you insist on using regex, the equivalent function to `REGEXP_SUBSTR` in PostgreSQL is `regexp_matches`:

```
select (regexp_matches('abc,afgg,afff,eef esfg eg,gegg,egegeg,vgb,grgg', '[^,]+','g'))[1] limit 1 offset 4;
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=72b728f15fe1d8b7a5c0cec8f32790fd